# Contact form error : The following from address failed

Tags: joomla-2.5, emails

I have a site developed in Joomla 2.5.9. Recently it moved to a new server and email is changed. I changed the email settings in Global configuration section. But now if I try to send email from Contact page it shows error like as follows

`The following from address failed:`

The following are my email configuration details :

```
mailer : SMTP
From mail : info@mydomain.com
sendmail path : /usr/sbin/sendmail
SMTP port : 25
SMSTP username : info@mydomain.com
SMTP password : xxxxx
SMTP Host : us2.smtp.mailhostbox.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe port `25` is blocked? Try port `587` instead. If im correct this is the documentation for your smtp host:
http://support.mailhostbox.com/configure-your-desktop-email-clients-to-send-and-receive-email/

Should state that the question you're asking isn't really specific. Could be anything that is going wrong!